# Disable updates to gridview based on Date

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am writing a web application in visual studio with data being read from SQL Server 2012 using Entities. I need a code either in the Front end or database that would check the PeriodStart (Date Field) against the current date (System) if the periodstart is greater then the current date, the user must be able to edit it, if not the user must not be able to do anything a message should appear.

Thanks

Comment: any code you are try

Comment: @NazirUllah I am trying to do a compare of the PeriodStart and System date as a start eg:    IF PeriodStart > GetDate() as Current

Comment: your question is not clear , please update with your code for better answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
            // assuming the the ShowEditLink resides in the first column of Grid
            //just changed the index of cells to where the EditLink resides
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];

            //if you are displaying the PeriodStart in the Grid using BoundField
            //Cells[1] means you are displaying the date in second column, just change the index
            //where you display the date
            DateTime periodStart = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[1].Text);
            if (lb != null) {
                if (periodStart > DateTime.Now)
                    lb.Visible = true;
                else
                    lb.Visible = false;
         }
    }
}
```